# Ti.UI.NOTIFICATION_DURATION_LONG not working in iOS?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

```
var myToastNotification = Ti.UI.createNotification();

myToastNotification.message = 'login Successfull';

myToastNotification.duration = Ti.UI.NOTIFICATION_DURATION_LONG;
```

I tried the above code for implementing toast. it is working fine with android but not in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property is only for Android.

```
NOTIFICATION_DURATION_LONG : 
Specifies a long duration for an Android Toast notification (Titanium.UI.Notification).
```